# How to integrate Aadhaar API in swift? As India Stack site is so confusing & not telling from where to get the API

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making an app which required a Aadhaar number for authentication. I searched out the complete India Stack site but did not get any way to get the API access. Please suggest from where and how can do the above work. or Is there any other site who can provide the API access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On India Stack they mention the list of technical resource from where you can select following API to integreate:

1. Aadhar bridge
2. emudhra
3. AuthBridge
4. OnGride
5. Aadhar API
6. digio etc.

You need to check with above API provider and select one of above as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Sarabjit, but I tried to contact them through mails but they did not replied yet .

Comment: Welcome Ravindra... may be they will reply in a while or try to contact with the support team over call.

Comment: Yes it could be the reason!